pod networking across nodes not working - flannel
I went through the setup in the K8s documentation and chose flannel as the network plugin. I came up with the steps below on Ubuntu VMs. All the pods come up and I can deploy new pods but I can't communicate with pods when they're on different nodes. For example, if I deploy nginx, I can't curl the pods on port 80. I know my yaml works because everything works as expected on EKS. I have the k8s nodes (1 master 2 workers) deployed in a single VPC in a single region and kubectl exec -it -- sh works on all the pods. Not sure where to look. There are no errors in kube-proxy or flannel pods. No errors in kubelet.
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
EOF

# Apply sysctl params without reboot
sudo sysctl --system

#Install Container runtime
https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/getting-started.md
wget https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/download/v1.7.21/containerd-1.7.21-linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar Cxzvf /usr/local containerd-1.7.21-linux-amd64.tar.gz

#download containerd.service
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containerd/containerd/main/containerd.service
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/systemd/system
sudo mv containerd.service /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable --now containerd
wget https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/releases/download/v1.1.14/runc.amd64
sudo install -m 755 runc.amd64 /usr/local/sbin/runc
wget https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/releases/download/v1.5.1/cni-plugins-linux-amd64-v1.5.1.tgz
sudo mkdir -p /opt/cni/bin
sudo tar Cxzvf /opt/cni/bin
sudo mkdir -p /etc/containerd
sudo sh -c '/usr/local/bin/containerd config default > /etc/containerd/config.toml'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gpg
sudo mkdir -p -m 755 /etc/apt/keyringsvi 
curl -fsSL https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.31/deb/Release.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg
echo 'deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/kubernetes-apt-keyring.gpg] https://pkgs.k8s.io/core:/stable:/v1.31/deb/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo systemctl enable --now kubelet


From the network perspective, there are requirements mentioned in this Kubernetes documentation. From the firewall perspective, you need to ensure the cluster traffic can pass the firewall on the nodes. Also make sure that  the list of ports you should have opened on the nodes provided by CoreOS website.

And also check whether the ip forwarding is enabled on all the nodes by using the below,
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

if not enable it like this and test it.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward


Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your problem? If not let me know, I am happy to assist you further.

Not sure how to mark your answers as helpful. I don't see an option in the UI.
